# In scala How do we find the latest record for each Customer?

Tags: scala

My input file is below . It contains some purchase details for each Customer.

**Input:**

```
 100,Surender,2015-01-23,PHONE,20000
 100,Surender,2015-01-24,LAPTOP,25000
 101,Ajay,2015-02-21,LAPTOP,40000
 101,Ajay,2015-03-10,MUSIC_SYSTEM,50000
 102,Vikram,2015-07-20,WATCH,60000
```

My requirement is I would like to find out the latest Purchase details for each Customer .

So the expected output is

**Expected OutPut:**

```
List(101,Ajay,2015-03-10,MUSIC_SYSTEM,50000)
List(100,Surender,2015-01-24,LAPTOP,25000)
List(102,Vikram,2015-07-20,WATCH,60000)
```

I tried the below code and it is giving me the expected output..

But this  below logic is somewhat similar to java .

**My Scala code :**

```
 package pack1
 import scala.io.Source
 import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
 object LatestObj {

 def main(args:Array[String])=
 {
    var maxDate ="0001-01-01"
    var actualData:List[String] =List()
    var resultData:ListBuffer[String] = ListBuffer()

    val myList=Source.fromFile("D:\\Scala_inputfiles\\records.txt").getLines().toList;
    val myGrped = myList.groupBy { x => x.substring(0,3) }
//println(myGrped)
     for(mappedIterator <- myGrped)
       {
         // println(mappedIterator._2)
            actualData =mappedIterator._2
            maxDate=findMaxDate(actualData)
            println( actualData.filter { x => x.contains(maxDate) })
       }


 }

   def findMaxDate( mytempList:List[String]):String =
   {
         var maxDate ="0001-01-01"
            for(m <- mytempList)
              {
                var transDate= m.split(",")(2)
                if(transDate > maxDate)
                {
                    maxDate =transDate
                }
     }

  return maxDate
  }

   }
```

Could some one help me on trying the same approach in a simpler way using scala?

Or The above code is the only way to achieve that logic?

Comment: "above code is the only way to achieve that logic?" No. You're writing Java-in-Scala. Take a look at the collections API (and probably a tutorial in Scala too). http://scala-lang.org/api/current/#package Although you found `filter` so it's a bit odd you didn't notice `max` and `maxBy`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even simpler version, also using a case class with coincidentally the same name. Doesn't remove bad records like Tzach's, though, and I leave everything as String.

```
case class Record(id: String, name: String, dateString: String, item: String, count: String)
  myList.map { line =>
    val Array(id, name, dateString, item, count) = line.split(",")
    Record(id, name, dateString, item, count)
  }
  .groupBy(_.id)
  .map(_._2.maxBy(_.dateString))
  .toList
```

Comment: Your Code gives  clear idea on achieving this logic with functional style, Thanks Much!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple version using `groupBy` and `reduce`, plus using a convenient case class to elegantly represent records:

```
case class Record(id: Int, username: String, date: Date, product: String, cost: Double)

val dateFormat: SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
val stringList = Source.fromFile("./records.txt").getLines().toList

// split by comma and parse into case class - while REMOVING bad records
val records = stringList.map(_.split(",")).collect {
  case Array(id, username, date, product, cost) => Record(id.toInt, username, dateFormat.parse(date), product, cost.toDouble)
}

// group by key, and reduce each group to latest record
val result = records.groupBy(_.id).map { _._2.reduce {
  (r1: Record, r2: Record) => if (r1.date.after(r2.date)) r1 else r2
}}

result.foreach(println)
// prints:
// Record(101,Ajay,Tue Mar 10 00:00:00 IST 2015,MUSIC_SYSTEM,50000.0)
// Record(100,Surender,Sat Jan 24 00:00:00 IST 2015,LAPTOP,25000.0)
// Record(102,Vikram,Mon Jul 20 00:00:00 IDT 2015,WATCH,60000.0)
```

Note that this implementation does not make any use of *mutable* variables or collections, which often simplifies the code significantly, and is considered more idiomatic for functional languages like Scala.

Comment: @ Tzach, Thanks a for this functional style of logic. It helps me a lot